# Посчитайте сумму чисел последовательности из n элементов

Tags: python

Олимпиадная задача, вот мое решение на python:

```
n = int(input())
print(sum(list(map(int, input().split()))))
```

Проваливаюсь по времени на числах 10^6<

Нужно чтобы решало за <1 секунду

Помогите пожалуйста сделать чтоб работало для всех чисел.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример входных и выходных данных.

Comment: Сумму какой последовательности вы считаете?  Произвольных случайных чисел, арифметической прогрессии, геометрической прогрессии, чисел Фибоначчи, ещё какого-то варианта?

Comment: Если числа всё-таки произвольные вводятся, то попробуйте убрать `list`, создание списка из генератора тут излишне, функция `sum` прекрасно из итератора сама всё прочитает, сэкономив память.

Answer (score 1):

Сумма [ряда из натуральных чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4_%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) от 1 до n вычисляется по формуле `n*(n+1)/2`

```
n = int(input())
print(n*(n+1)//2)
```

```
4544445454545454545454554
10325992244669421487603346891698760330578512396735
```

Comment: В задании не была речь ни об арифметической или какой-то другой специальной последовательности, ни о ее первом элементе. :-(